# Recurring Payment 2Checkout .NET Api

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, 2checkout

I created a sandbox account with 2Chechout and followed the [.NET tutorial](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/payment-api/tutorial) on how to create a sale. I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to create a recurring sale using the same api. Can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. To pass in a recurring sale via the Payment API, you will need to omit the "total" parameter entirely, and instead pass in recurring lineitems using a sub-object of the "charge" array.

Example edited from 2Checkout:

```
    TwoCheckoutConfig.SellerID = "901248156";
    TwoCheckoutConfig.PrivateKey = "8CE03B2D-FE41-4C53-9156-52A8ED5A0FA3";
    // TwoCheckoutConfig.Sandbox = true;    #Uncomment to use Sandbox

    try
    {
        var Billing = new AuthBillingAddress();
        Billing.addrLine1 = "123 test st";
        Billing.city = "Columbus";
        Billing.zipCode = "43123";
        Billing.state = "OH";
        Billing.country = "USA";
        Billing.name = "Testing Tester";
        Billing.email = "example@2co.com";
        Billing.phoneNumber = "5555555555";

        var LineItem = new AuthLineitem();
        LineItem.duration = "Forever";
        LineItem.name = "Recurrencing Item Name";
        LineItem.price = (decimal)10.00;
        LineItem.productId = "12345";
        LineItem.quantity = 1;
        LineItem.startupFee = (decimal)10.00;
        LineItem.recurrence = "1 Month";
        LineItem.tangible = "N";
        LineItem.type = "product";

        var LineItems = new List<AuthLineitem>();
        LineItems.Add(LineItem);

        var Customer = new ChargeAuthorizeServiceOptions();
        //Customer.total = (decimal)1.00; --> omit this
        Customer.currency = "USD";
        Customer.merchantOrderId = "123";
        Customer.billingAddr = Billing;
        Customer.token = Request["token"];
        Customer.lineItems = LineItems; // --> add this

        var Charge = new ChargeService();

        var result = Charge.Authorize(Customer);
        Console.Write(result);
    }
    catch (TwoCheckoutException e)
    {
        Console.Write(e);
    }
```

This should work for recurring sales.

Comment: Got error on Charge.Authorize(Customer); 
error : "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s"